# Golang – Testing for interface implementation of underlying value?

Tags: go, interface, assert, implementation, member-functions

So, I was trying to find the solution via the search and web-search. Wasn't successful.
This has likely a simple solution, but probably I'm just a bit messed up.

I have prepared the following example in [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ryix0Zntcv8).

```golang
// main.go

type myInterface interface {
    Function1() string
    Function2() int
}

type notMyStruct struct {
    myInterface
    // arbitrary implementation
}

func myFunc(val myInterface) {
    fmt.Printf("%T %v", val, val)

    fmt.Printf("this failes: %q", val.Function1())
    // how to safely test, 
    // whether the underlying value
    // has implemented the interface?
}

func main() {
    myFunc(&notMyStruct{})
}
```

It consists of an interface `myInterface`, an arbitrary struct `notMyStruct`, which has the embedded interface (but not actually implemented) and some other arbitrary fields.
Now this struct is injected into `myFunc`, which the go compiler will accept, due to the fact that the interface is embedded.
But if `myFunc` tries to call a Function of the interface, it panics – understandably.

Assuming, I don't know the actual struct implementation (because I'm not in control of the interface-implementing code):

**How can I reliably test, whether a given underlying value has an actual implementation of the method set (`Function1` and `Function2`) defined by the interface?**

I assume, this is solvable with `reflect` package (performance is not an issue here). Maybe there's any other solutions thinkable? Type assertion didn't seem to work out for me...

Comment: The type `myStruct` has implementations of `Function1` and `Function2` that call through methods with the same name on the `myInterface` field.  The `reflect` package and type assertions will not tell you that the methods will panic.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks for your fast response. What would you suggest then?

Comment: It is not possible to determine if a method will panic without some knowledge about the implementation.  If you know that a method forwards to a method on an interface field, then you can test the field for nil.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Alright, that's prior to calling the method. And inside that function `myFunc`? How to assert an existing implementation?

Comment: It's not your job to make sure the implementation does not panic. Someone could pass an implementation which has explicitly defined the methods but also they explicitly call `panic()`. You could not detect that and that wouldn't be "any better" implementation.

Comment: @icza so form the content of linked threads, I believe `recover()` is the only option I have inside that method, if I want to guarantee smooth execution.
Thanks for the hints

Comment: @m0r0n Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) in `myFunc` to assert that the interface value is a specific concrete type: `if nms, ok := val.(*notMyStruct); ok && nms.myInterface == nil { /* call will panic */ }`

Comment: Also note that this is possible, shared it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61448767/1705598).