# How to correctly check io.Reader for nil?

Tags: go, pointers, interface, null

If you create a variable of type `bytes.Buffer` (without initialization) and assign it to a field of type `io.Reader`, then after checking `io.Reader` for nil there will be an error: `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`. How to check this correctly to avoid such errors?

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/10q0rJZ2S5h)

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Request struct {
    Body io.Reader
}

func main() {
    var data *bytes.Buffer

    request := &Request{
        Body: data,
    }

    if request.Body != nil {
        ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body) // panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning a nil pointer to an interface? If you need to check if an interface is nil, don't assign a dynamic type to the value. If you need to check if the pointer is nil, do it before assigning it to the interface.

Comment: Yes, in this example it is easy to check, but if we access io.Reader somewhere deep in some library, and the value was assigned somewhere in another project, then we would like to somehow check that the user of this library assigned correct data in io.Reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if an [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) (or any other interface) value is `nil`, you simply compare it to `nil`.

Whether a non-`nil` `io.Reader` is a meaningful implementation, that's another question.

E.g. is this implementation meaningful?

```
type panicReader struct{}

func (panicReader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    panic("foo")
}
```

`panicReader` certainly implements `io.Reader`, but whenever you call its `Read()` method, it will always panic.

There is [`bytes.Buffer`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer). A pointer to it implements `io.Reader`. But calling [`Buffer.Read()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer.Read) on a `nil` `*bytes.Buffer` pointer value will panic. But not because you can't call methods on `nil` pointer receivers, but because the implementation of `bytes.Buffer.Read()` tries to dereference the pointer receiver, and this dereference operation is what causes the panic:

```
// Excerpt from bytes.Buffer.Read implementation 
func (b *Buffer) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    b.lastRead = opInvalid
    if b.empty() {
    // ...
}
```

You can't make a general conclusion here (just yet). See this `io.Reader` implementation:

```
type myBuffer struct{}

var count int

func (*myBuffer) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    if len(p) > 0 {
        count++
        if count >= 10 {
            return 0, io.EOF
        }
        p[0] = 'a'
        return 1, nil
    }
    return 0, nil
}
```

`*myBuffer` implements `io.Reader`, and its `Read()` method does not use the pointer receiver value. What does this mean? You *can* call `Read()` on a `nil` `*myBuffer` value:

```
var data *myBuffer

request := &Request{
    Body: data,
}

if request.Body != nil {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(data), err)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ohJHMsAHXk_H)):

```
aaaaaaaaa <nil>
```

So the conclusion is this: *usually* types that have methods with pointer receiver require a non-`nil` pointer because they use the *pointed* object (in case of `bytes.Buffer` they use the fields of the pointed struct). To use such types (to have a meaningful implementation of implemented interfaces), you often need a non-`nil` pointer value for the methods to "work". This–however–is not always a requirement as the above `myBuffer` implementation shows. It's your job to always read the documentation of the used types and methods to avoid such misuses (e.g. trying to use a `nil` `*bytes.Buffer`).

See related question:

[Hiding nil values, understanding why Go fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-go-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

[Go reflection with interface embedded in struct - how to detect "real" functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988632/go-reflection-with-interface-embedded-in-struct-how-to-detect-real-functions/61448767#61448767)